# Rank of a matrix sum: equality case

Tags: matrix-rank

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m} $ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. It is known that $rank(A+B)\leq rank(A)+rank(B)$. My question is when does equality holds for this inequality? What is the condition for the case of more than 2 matrices?

Comment: There are necessary conditions. For example, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129157/prove-that-if-ranka-b-ranka-rankb-then-cola-%E2%88%A9-colb-0). In general, the matrix sum is not well-behaved with respect to rank. Consider $0=A+(-A)$. So there is no nice necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: In that case, "if the equality holds, then ... " I am looking for possibly not an answer but an insight since as you mentioned matrix sum is not well-behaved wrt rank which results with the equality not a result of the equality.

Comment: The insight is indeed to consider the column spaces, as in the above [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129157/prove-that-if-ranka-b-ranka-rankb-then-cola-%E2%88%A9-colb-0).